# Можно ли забиндить клиентский сокет?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, сокет

Пытаюсь сделать сокет-клиент, в задании сказано, что необходимо реализовывать отправку всегда с определенного порта (к примеру 50000-го). Пытался вызывать `bind` метод перед `send`, первый раз все отлично получается, сообщение отправляется с того адреса, который я задал, но в последующие разы выходит исключение, что "обычно разрешено использовать только один адрес". После перезагрузки формы, все опять повторяется, 1-е сообщение ок, потом выходит исключение. Прочитал, что такое происходит, потому что порт не освободился после первого раза и по советам пытался закрывать клиент `close`, делать в конце `dispose` и `send_socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true)`, к сожалению ничего не помогает. Это вообще возможно отправлять всегда с одного заданного порта? Сообщений должно большое количество отправляться, может быть пару раз в секунду.
Код моего клиента:

```
    private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string local_host = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
        string local_ip_address = Dns.GetHostByName(local_host).AddressList[0].ToString();
        IPEndPoint send_point = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(local_ip_address), 50000);

        Socket send_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        IPEndPoint connected_point = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textBoxIPListen.Text), 
                                                    Convert.ToInt32(textBoxPortListen.Text));
        try
        {
            send_socket.Bind(send_point);
            send_socket.Connect(connected_point);
            byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("TestTest");
            send_socket.Send(data);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            send_socket.Close();
            ((IDisposable)send_socket).Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте не просто закрывать сокет, а делать shutdown для него. Похоже, вы повторно пытаетесь использовать зарезервированный адрес. После перезапуска формы ресурсы "железно" высвобождаются, и соответственно, вы можете заново использовать данные для регистрации сокета. Там вообще есть группа методов, они используются в разных сценариях (Shutdown, Disconnect, close). Еще было бы хорошей идеей, вытащить ресурсы сокета из формы в отдельный метод, и при старте программы производить инициализацию сети, а потом уже, связывать эти ресурсы с какой либо логикой. К примеру, создайте отдельно методы для создания сокета на данном адресе и свяжите его с действием нажатия по кнопке connect, аналогично с disconnect.

Comment: Ой, забыл упомянуть, тоже пробовал `shutdown` и `disconnect` метод, к сожалению, результат такой же. А по поводу второго, да, спасибо, тоже подумывал об этом, прост для тестирования проще всего, когда все сразу :) Пока эдакий черновой вариант.

Comment: send_socket.Disconnect(false);
  send_socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
  send_socket.Close(); так пробовали?

Comment: Так тоже сейчас попробовал, такое же исключение выбивает :/

Comment: А ты пробовал другие порты? типа 24016 например. Еще, можешь netstat показать?  После запуска проги и до запуска.

Comment: В смысле изначально использовать другой порт или имеете ввиду в процессе отправки менять ? Если изначально другой порт, то уже перепробовал рандомно с 49000-65000 (те, которые система сама определяет без bind), попробовал и 24016, результат всё тот же. А какие именно данные нужны с netstat?

Comment: Интересно, после того, как ((IDisposable)send_socket).Dispose() срабатывает, что с портами происходит.

Comment: К слову,  сюда смотрели? https://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/web/level3/3_2.php

Comment: Да, по нему изначально и учился по сокетам. Многие вещи оттуда и взял.